# Eslint error property 'artist' does not exist react en visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, reactjs, react-native

Tengo el error ya mencionado

> message: 'Property 'artist' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.'at: '16,56' source: 'js'

Pero el proyecto inicia normal sin problemas no se si me falto instalar algo del Eslint o configurar en `.eslintrc.js`, Estoy usando Visual studio code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    import {

     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     View,
    Image,

    } from 'react-native';

  export default class ArtistBox extends Component {
    render() {

const { image, name, likes, comment } = this.props.artist
const likeicon = (<Icon name="md-heart-outline" size={30} color="gray" />)
const comenticon = (<Icon name="ios-chatboxes-outline" size={30} color="gray" />)

return (



  <View style={styles.artisbox}>
    <Image style={styles.hayley} source={{ uri: image }} />

    <View style={styles.info}>
      <Text style={styles.name} >{name}</Text>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.setupicon}>
          <Icon>{likeicon}</Icon>
          <Text style={styles.texsetup}>{likes}</Text>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.setupicon}>
          <Icon>{comenticon}</Icon>
          <Text style={styles.texsetup}>{comment}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    </View>

  </View>


      );
    }
  }
```